# How can I name the array after the user input?

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to name the array by the client name that was being input by the staff, the input could and will be with spaces such as 'John Smith' therefore the whitespace needs to be removed to become JohnSmith. I have tried looking on google but I didn't find any meaningful results

{

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void clientAddress_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (userInput.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Empty field!");
        }
        else if (listBox.Items.Contains(userInput.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Name already taken!");
        }
        else
        {
        string clientName = userInput.Text.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
        string[] clientName = new string { { userInput.Text, "Unknown", "Unknown" } };
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Why do you want to give a variable a name of a client that is entered by the user? That doesn't make any sense to me. Maybe you need an identifier, then use a `Dictionary<string, string>` and add the name as key (but what's the use of it, what's the value?).

Comment: Maybe a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot dynamically name the variable in your application.  But you can use the what the user typed in as the key in your [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

```
// lets say you have a Dictionary for your client list
string[] clientData = new string { { userInput.Text, "Unknown", "Unknown" } };
clientList.Add(userInput.Text, clientData);
```

Comment: Strange. Upvotes for Objective-C answer in C# question :O

Comment: Very strange on both accounts. Nice avatar, though..

Comment: May I expect a justification from upvoters please ?

Comment: I had objective-C on the brain.  Will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd replace spaces with a different character, such as underscore, in these cases. string.Replace(" ", "_") works fine then.